# CSS file doesn't work when put on a remote server

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting my HTML code to link to my CSS code once I FTP it onto the server.  Both CSS File and HTML File are in the same directory on the server. I would like to note that I have attempted to clear the browsers cache and use a different browser and nothing seems to be working.

**Here is my HTML code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <base href="http://people.rit.edu/~username/rop/" target="_blank">
        <title> My ROP Home Page </title>
        <link href= "style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "things">
                <h1> All About Me </h2>
            <div id = "activities">
                <h2> I'm a fan of video games </h2>
                    <p> As the title suggests, I love to play video games.  I have been playing video games since I was 8 years old.  I started with a Nintendo 64 and have since then begged my parents for every new system to date (obviously that wont work anymore).
                        This hobby is part of the reason I wish to become a web developer.  When I was young, I spent time browising websites like IGN, and thought that one day I could make something like that.  Now I set my sights a little higher, seeing as I want to be able to develope professional websites.
                    </p>
                <h2> My Favorite Food is Pizza ( I Can't get enough!) </h2>
                    <p> Seriously, I could have Pizza everyday of the week and not get sick of it.  I like all kinds of toppings except pineapple.  I must have pizza at least once a week no matter how unhealthy that may be.  Of course, local buisnesses make better pizza then large chains.
                    </p>
                <h2> I am a SOIS student focusing on Web Development and other IT centered courses</h2>
                    <p> SOIS is the School of Individualized Study.  Basically I create a major that is more in line with what I want to get out of R.I.T.  Students of SOIS must pick two specializations in order to create a degree.  Other than that, it is just like other degrees at R.I.T with many of the same requirments.
                        For example, I specialize in Web Development (front-end) and some networking.
                    </p>
                <h2> I'm a Big Fan of cheesey monster movies </h2>
                <p> For reasons unknown, I have been drawn to old Godzilla movies that clearly have not aged well.  I think it's neat to see how they made those films without cgi or technology.  Seeing the behind the scenes of the mini cities is always a neat experience for film fans.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "brian">
        <img src ="brian.jpg" alt="brian" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
h1, h2, p{
    background-color: #100733;
}
title {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.things     {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#brian {
    float: right;
}
#activities {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
}

p {
    background-color: #100733;
    color: white;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: works fine in jsfiddle, only problem I see is the doctype not being opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you forget about the opening `<` in the first line (Doctype)?

Make it `<!DOCTYPE html>` and be sure that your `style.css` file is in the same directory as your index file.

EDIT:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /~username/rop/ was not found on this server.
>
> Apache Server at people.rit.edu Port 443

So it does not work because of the `base` tag. Are you sure that the provided location works? When I open `https://people.rit.edu/~username/rop/` it gives 443.

EDIT 2:

Change:

`<base href="http://people.rit.edu/~bxa9985/rop/" target="_blank">`

To:

`<base href="https://people.rit.edu/~bxa9985/rop/" target="_blank">`

Comment: oh no that was when i copied it over to stack over flow, my code has it

Comment: yeah, "username" in the link is something else I took it out for privacy reasons.  The url works for me but it's just the html not the css

Comment: So it all works on your "local environment" but does not work when your upload on the remote server, right?

Comment: So by saying "does not work on remote" - you mean, HTML is unstyled, right? Try opening the remote page and check the console. Any errors in it? Do you use any dev tools / Chrome Dev Tools / Firebug etc?

Comment: yeah it is unstyled i get "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://people.rit.edu/~bxa9985/rop/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://people.rit.edu/~bxa9985/rop/style.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: @BrianAndris OK, check my answer again.

Comment: In a nutshell, serve all assets in HTTPS if page is on HTTPS.

Comment: Oh my god, that did it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Better still make the `href` in the `base` tag protocol agnostic:`<base href="//people.rit.edu/~bxa9985/rop/" target="_blank">` if there is a chance to be serving both `http` and `https`. Also see this article : https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/, particularly why you should be serving everything https anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**

Make sure that you can access the css file using the browser.

If your url is, say `example.com`, and you access your html file like this `example.com/index.html`, then be sure that you can actually see the css if you enter `example.com/style.css`

It may be that you haven't set the permissions right in the server if you uploaded the files through ftp.

**Then other considerations**

> Make sure that you have the first opening character `<`

See this

```
   !DOCTYPE HTML>
```

should be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

> Take out spaces after and before equal sign (`=`)

this

```
<link href= "style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

should be like this

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be your CSS file name doesn't match the HTML file, I faced this problem and my solution is I changed 'S' in `Style.css` from capital to small, and worked for me.